# How to combine several dicts into one string? (both key and value)

Tags: python

I have two dicts:

```
dict_1 = {'key1': 'value1'}
dict_2 = {'key2': 'value2'}
```

I would like to combine them into one string, similar to this (doesn't have to look exactly like that):

```
key1 value1 - key2 value2
```

I tried to approach this somehow like this:

```
final_string = ' - '.join(chain(map(lambda x: x, {**dict_1, **dict_2})))
```

But it gives me this:

```
key1 - key2
```

I am not sure what to change to get both key and value out of it?
Could someone please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small tweak to your code:

```
' - '.join(map(lambda kv: ' '.join(kv), {**dict_1, **dict_2}.items()))
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `items()`

```py
' - '.join([' '.join(i) for i in ({**dict_1, **dict_2}.items())])
```

```
'key1 value1 - key2 value2'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use list comprehension as:

```
res = ' - '.join([f"{k} {v}" for d in [dict_1, dict_2] for k, v in d.items() ])
print(res)
```

Comment: I didn't thought about list comprehension but it does work, thanks!